# Errors while installing VMWare Player Tools

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, vmware-player

When I open VMWare player, I get a prompt to install VMWare Player tools. When I click on Download and Install, it shows this error:

> Failed to run /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/vmware-installer '--required' '--console' '--install-component=/home/dell/.cache/vmware/cds/cdstmp_tools-linux_10.2.5_9474260/vmware-tools-linux-10.2.5-8068393.x86_64.component' as user root.
>   Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.

I also have read that it is not recommended to launch GUI applications as `root` or with `sudo`. So is there any other option to install VMWare tools from Terminal/Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I changed GNOME to GNOME on Xorg, and when I tried to install VMWare tools it asked me for authentication and then that were installed successfully. Earlier it never asked me for authentication and showed the above mentioned error. I don't know the explanation but love to learn about that.